# "Now that [a certain criterion] is in place" in Japanese

Tags: grammar, syntax, english-to-japanese

In English you can say things like

> Now that an X is here we can discuss Y

with the implication being that X is a criterion that must be in place to continue. A similar structure can be used to start off new ideas: "Now that I'm going to the store" after which you list all the stuff your going to buy etc.

How would sentences like these translate into Japanese? I was thinking something like

> 店に行くことになるなら...

but something tells me that sounds wrong.

Answer (score 5):

＞　"Now that  X is here　 we can discuss Y"

- X君も来たことだし、Yの話をしましょうか。
- X君も揃ったことだし、Yの話ができますね。
- じゃあ、X君も来たんで、Yを議論しましょう。
- では、 Xさんも お見えになりましたので、　議題Y　に移っても よろしいでしょうか？

> "Now that I'm going to the store"  -- after which you list all the stuff your going to buy, etc.

Here's something you might say, while driving to go to Store A :

A店に行くんだから、 ｘ、ｙ、ｚ　を買っとくか。

A店に行くんだし、・・・

A店に行くと言えば、・・・

A店と言えば、・・・

A店に行くからには、・・・

A店に行くとなったら、・・・

A店に行くついでに、・・・

A店に行くと決まったからには、・・・

A店に行くのは珍しいから、・・・

A店に行くのは珍しいし、・・・

A店に行くことは滅多に無いし、・・・

Most common (or my favorites) are :

- A店に行くんだから、ｘ、ｙ、ｚ　を買っとくか。
- A店に行くんだし、・・・
- A店に行くついでに、・・・

> http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%22now+that%22
>
> 18件
>
> now that it's come to this  ----- 
>   〔事態｛じたい｝などが〕こうなったら、かくなる上は
>
> now that things have come to this pass   ----- 
>   かくなる上は、こうなった以上は、今となっては
>
> now that I've taken the trouble to   ----- 
>   せっかく ～ したのに

I think this last example is wrong.  It should be せっかく ～ したんだし、 . . .  etc.

---

> detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp › 地域、旅行、お出かけ › 国内 › 観光地、行楽地
>
> 大学生で箱根に行こうとなったら、日帰りでも温泉やユネッサンに行くものですか？

This is like 　　　 A店に行くとなったら、・・・

行こう because it's a [Let's go] form, and possibly because it's a hypothetical